# I can´t run "py --version" on Visual Studio Code´s terminal

Tags: python

I am trying to install the Godaddy´s package in Python. So I ended up in this site that explaines how to install the packages: [text](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/) but I folowed the instructions to run "py --version" and I got this error: py : El término 'py' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió
correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

- py --version
- ~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (py:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    [image: Terminal´s image]

I tried running "py --version"

Comment: Have you tried `python --version`? There is no reference to `py --version` in the documentation you linked.

Answer (score 2):

Have you've tried running `python --version` or `python3 --version` instead?

Those usually work where other ways doesnt, unless there's a problem with your python installation.

(TIP: `python -V` or `python3 -V` also works, but make sure they're uppercase)